# Why do these SVGs render differently, when the only thing that differs is how the markup is formatted?

Tags: html, svg

The content inside the tags in the two SVGs below are identical. Why do they still render differently (in a browser)?

Is this an SVG thing or an HTML thing?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 50" width="600" height="50">
  <text x="20" y="20">
    <tspan>Text </tspan>
    <tspan fill="#00f">
    <tspan fill="#f00">Inner tspan before</tspan><tspan id="t" x="168.59"> Outer tspan between </tspan><tspan fill="#f00">Inner tspan after</tspan> </tspan></text></svg>
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 50" width="600" height="50">
  <text x="20" y="20">
    <tspan>Text </tspan>
    <tspan fill="#00f">
    <tspan fill="#f00">Inner tspan before</tspan>
    <tspan id="t" x="168.59"> Outer tspan between </tspan><tspan fill="#f00">Inner tspan after</tspan> </tspan></text></svg>
```

Comment: whitespace is significant inside text elements. Why is that a surprise, it's exactly the same in HTML.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Please tell me if I am blind. I think that whitespace is exactly the same inside text elements in the examples above.

Comment: Ahha, of course, you mean that there is difference in whitespace in TEXT elements :-). I was so preoccupied with looking at the tspan elements. Okay, I agree with you, it makes sense.